# google map android api v2 marker shadows

Tags: android, shadow, marker, google-maps-android-api-2

cannot find an answer in the official documentation, so is there a way do have a GoogleMap draw marker shadows automatically like the old MapView did?
i know i can draw it manually but i'm wondering if that handy behavior is still there

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read, google and research the answer is no. You could do something in code to automatically create it etc. but I think the best option is to draw it.